Why is "gear" object non manifold in Reaper
I want to postprocess gears with some booleans and all was failing, so I started investigating and it turns out even the default gears is nonmanifold! Why? And how to fix that easily?


Adding a Gear object and checking it with Blender's 3D Print Toolbox addon shows that the two inner loops of the gear are non manifold.

Selecting both loops in Edge mode and then using the Edge > BridgeEdgeLoop menu will fill the gap and checking again now shows 0 Non Manifold Edges.


Thanks. Any idea why the gear is like this? A bug perhaps?

No idea I'm afraid. It's always been like that and I doubt it was written with 3D printing in mind.
